# Loading multi-texture 3ds c++

Tags: opengl, c++

I have a question about loading 3ds using [this](http://www.spacesimulator.net/wiki/index.php?title=Tutorials:3ds_Loader) tutorial. I want to use more than one texture on the model (because [here](http://www.scifi3d.com/list.asp?intGenreID=10&intCatID=10) all the models have more than one) but it seems that this library can't do that. Do you know any other alternatives or a way to edit this existing library to reach my aim?

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [AssImp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/).

It's a fairly comprehensive library with importing code already written for you and even provides a sample C++ OpenGL program [here](http://assimp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/assimp/trunk/samples/SimpleOpenGL/).

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know, but if you read a little the documentation of the file format, it should not be that hard, since the space simulator done the most part for you, you just need to tweak a little the code to add support for this.

You can find a lot about the 3DS File format [googling it](http://www.google.com.br/webhp?q=3ds%20file%20format%20structure)

Also, here's a search made for you: http://the-labs.com/Blender/3DS-details.html

I think the relevant part for you is at the chunks 4140H, 4170H, A200H(Maybe), F140H(For animations)

Good luck :D